# How to import a variable from a static class

Tags: java, static-methods

This program is supposed to create a fraction when an object is created in the main method and use other methods to add different objects. I am using a class that contains the methods for adding and multiplying the fractions. However, in the class where I have the constructor and the accessors and mutators, I also have another two methods which update the values of `numerator` and `denominator` using the methods from the previously mentioned class. How do I access the variables from said class?

This is the class with the constructor and where I am trying to import the variables:

```
public class Fraction {

    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;  
    }

    // Getters and setters left out for brevity

    // Calculate by using the FractionMath class, then update
    // the numerator and denominator from the returned Fraction
    
    public void addFraction(Fraction other) {
        
    }

    /**
    * Updates this fraction by multiplying another fraction
    * @param other Fraction to multiple to existing fraction
    */

    //Calculate by using the FractionMath class, then update
    //the numerator and denominator from the returned Fraction
    
    public void multiplyFraction(Fraction other) {
        
    }

    public String toString() {
        return numerator + " / " + denominator;    
    }
}
```

This is the class with the methods add and multiply:

```
public class FractionMath {

    public static Fraction add(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) {
        int numerator = frac1.getNumerator() * frac2.getDenominator() +
                        frac2.getNumerator() * frac1.getDenominator();
        int denominator = frac1.getDenominator() * frac2.getDenominator();

        return new Fraction(numerator, denominator);
    }

    public static Fraction multiply(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) {
        int numerator = frac1.getNumerator() * frac2.getNumerator();
        int denominator = frac1.getDenominator() * frac2.getDenominator();

        return new Fraction(numerator, denominator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some terminology issues here: There are no static variables in your class. There are static methods.

A static variable would be `public static int someNumber = 0;`

It is not a static class (Such a thing doesn't really exist in Java), but a class with static methods. There are static inner classes, but they aren't really static in the way you'd have static variables or methods.

To call a static method, you'd just use the class name and the method name, e.g.

`Fraction result = FractionMath.add(frac1, frac2);`